# (V2.83.0) Mantaflow fire + gas - How to scale emitter

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, fire

I have been testing mantaflow for the last few days and have a simple problem.

I want to create a rocket launch animation. Now fire and smoke should come out of the engine. This works great. But the smoke reaches the edge of the domain relatively quickly, so I have to enlarge it. Unfortunately, my "flame" (emitter) is also significantly larger than the engine.

Can I increase my domain without increasing the flame or can I scale my emitter that I just create a small simulation result with a big domain?

Greetings :)

Comment: Can I scale my emitter that I just create a small simulation result with a big domain? Yes. To properly view this, your grid size will have to be high enough.

Comment: i scaled it up under scene properties > units > unit scale value to 1000.00 but nothing changed

Comment: [Resolution Divisions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/domain/settings.html)